# href with you tube video

Tags: javascript, php, html, youtube

I want to clcik on below small youtube link and display the big.

I want to **video1**  **video2** **video3** **video4**  to display the video link like this
   --- this is only display.

After click this video then apear in the big video in same page.

Also below is the code:

I really appreciate your time. thanks

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:20%;top:20%;height:60%;width:60%">
<iframe id="myvideo" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=vt4X7zFfv4k" 
style="position:relative;height:100%;width:100%"></iframe>
<div style="text-align:center">
<a href="#null" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=LRBIVRwvUeE'">video1</a> | 
<a href="#null" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=bT4WGQVmQf8'">video2</a> | 
<a href="#null" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=Wz1W_omigwg'">video3</a> | 
<a href="#null" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=LRBIVRwvUeE'">video4</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please attach screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security reasons you can not listen to a click on an iframe. You can replace your iframes in your playlist with images (eg. video-thumbnails).

You can get thumbnails of a certain Youtube-Video like that

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

So you need to update your code like that:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:20%;top:20%;height:60%;width:60%">
    <iframe id="myvideo" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=vt4X7zFfv4k" style="position:relative;height:100%;width:100%"></iframe>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=LRBIVRwvUeE'">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/W-Q7RMpINVo/1.jpg" />
      </a> |
      <a href="#null" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=bT4WGQVmQf8'">
        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/bT4WGQVmQf8/1.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jB7TM/)

Comment: Thanks alot, Is it possible to same look to you tube video as images.

Comment: Unfortunately Youtube does not provide this. But you can do that on your own. Please consider to upvote or mark this answer as accepted if it fits your needs.